# Отобразить cefsharp элемент через DirectX

Tags: c#, winforms

Возможно ли отображение cefsharp элемента ( браузера ) через DirectX?

Comment: В конcоли вряд-ли такое возможно, а так, укажите, winforms у вас или wpf, или что-то еще? Добавьте тег к вопросу.

Comment: Извините, забыл добавить.У меня wf